# About the relation $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{P'(z_j)}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $P(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n\ge 2$ with $n$ distinct zeroes $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n$. Explain why it follows that every zero of $P$ is simple, and show that $$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{P'(z_j)}=0.$$

I am able to show that every zero of $P$ is simple, but for the rest a huge calculation is coming. Is there any simple method to reduce the last calculation?

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $P(z)=a\prod_{i=1}^n (z-z_i)$ with $n\geq 2$ and $a\not=0$. Then 
$$P'(z_j)=a {\prod_{i\not=j}^n(z_j-z_i)}.$$
Hence
$$Q(z):=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{{\prod_{i\not=j}^n(z-z_i)}}{P'(z_j)}$$
is a polynomial of degree $< n$ such that $Q(z_j)=1/a$ for $j=1,\dots,n$, which implies that $Q$ is identically $1/a$. Therefore the coefficient of $z^{n-1}$ of $Q$ (note that $n-1\geq 1$)  is zero:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{P'(z_j)}=0.$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1). :-)

Comment: Will you please tell me why $Q(z_j)=1/a\implies Q\equiv 1$

Comment: The polynomial $Q-1/a$ of degree $<n$ has $n$ distinct zeroes, therefore $Q-1/a$ is identically zero.

Comment: yeah, got it. Sorry for the silly question.