Paradoxical results concerning the residue theorem
I'm having some conceptual difficulties understanding this "paradox" from the residue theorem.
Residue theorem statement
Assume the domain $\Omega$ is simply connected. Let $f:\Omega\setminus\{z_1,\cdots,z_n\}\to \Bbb C$ be an analytic functions. Let $\gamma$ be a cycle in $\Omega\setminus\{z_1,\cdots,z_n\}$. Then we have $$\oint_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz =2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^nW_\gamma(z_k)\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_k}f.$$ Here $W_\gamma(\cdot)$ denote the winding number.
Now consider a polynomial $P(z)$ of degree at least 2 such that all roots of $P$ lie in the upper-half plane. For example, $P(z)=(z-i)(z-2i)$. Then we can construct a semicircular contour: 
By residue theorem, we have $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_k}\frac{1}{P(z)}=\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{dz}{P(z)} = \int_C \frac{dz}{P(z)}+\int_{-R}^R  \frac{dx}{P(x)}.$$
As $|z|=R\to\infty$, $$\int_C \frac{dz}{P(z)} \le 2\pi R \max_{\xi\in C}\frac{1}{|P(\xi)|}=2\pi R\cdot O\left(\frac{1}{R^n}\right)$$ so the integral over $C$ goes to $0$. Therefore, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{dx}{P(x)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_k}\frac{1}{P(z)}.$$
However, if we construct the semicircular contour on the lower-half plane, 
Then $1/P$ is holomorphic inside $\Gamma'$ which means, by Cauchy's theorem, $\oint_{\Gamma'}\frac{dz}{P(z)}=0$. Similarly, $\int_{C'} \frac{dz}{P(z)}=0$ as $R\to\infty$. In this case, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{P(x)}=0.$$
But this need not be the case since the sums of residues is not always zero. Where's the contradiction?
My guess is that it has something to do with residues at infinity but I can't sense of it completely.

There is no contradiction because the sum of all residues of $1/P$ is zero, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436011/42969

If $P$ has degree $\ge2$, then $\mathrm{Res}(1/P;\infty)=0$. Expand it at infinity, and note that $1/P\to0$ at infinity so the Taylor series is $1/P(z)=-\mathrm{Res}(1/P;\infty)\cdot z^{-1}+c_2z^{-2}+\cdots$, but the fact $P$ is of degree $\ge2$ entails $z/P(z)\to0$ as well, so the residue vanishes. This is more or less the same observation that $\oint_C1/P\to0$.
It is therefore no surprise that $\sum_{\text{roots of $P$}}\mathrm{Res}(1/P)=-\mathrm{Res}(1/P;\infty)=0$.

I see why the residue at infinity argument works. Could we perhaps generalize this to ANY functions that only have poles on the upper-half plane with sufficiently fast decay at infinity?

@HetianFu Well, in a sense? If $z/f(z)\to0$ as $z\to\infty$ and $f$ is entire then $\sum\mathrm{Res}(1/f)=0$ where the sum is over all zeroes of $f$ if $f$ has finitely many roots. Things could be a bit subtle in the infinite case
